# Banach-Mazur game and infinite products

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, infinite-games

Studying the article "Games that involve set theory or topology" of Marion Scheepers, I found the following result

**Theorem 46** Let $\{(X_{i}, \tau_{i}) : i\in I  \}$ be a family of topological spaces. If for every countable subset $J$ of $I$, Player I does not have a winning strategy in the game $\textsf{BM} (\prod_{j\in J}X_{j},
   \square_{j\in J} \tau_{j}  ),$ then Player I does not have a winning strategy in $\textsf{BM} (\prod_{i\in I}X_{i},
   \prod_{i\in I} \tau_{i}  ).$

Where $\textsf{BM}(X)$ denotes the Banach-Mazur game played on a topological space $X$.

So far I had no success in proving the theorem, the author only states the result without mentioning any reference. I would like to know if you could give me some idea about it.

Remember that The Banach-Mazur game on $X$, $\textsf{BM}(X)$, is played as follows: Players I
and II play an inning per positive integer. In the $n$-th inning Player I chooses a nonempty open set $A_n$; Player II responds with a nonempty open set $B_n \subseteq A_n$. Player I must also obey the rule that for each $n$, $A_{n+1} \subseteq B_n$. 
A play $A_1, B_1, \cdots A_n, B_n$ is won by Player II if $\bigcap_{n\in\omega}T_n \not=\emptyset$; otherwise, Player I wins.

One of the most important results in this regard is the following

**Theorem**  A nonempty topological space $X$ is a Baire space if and only if Player I has no winning strategy in the Banach-Mazur game $\textsf{BM}(X)$.

**Some remarks**

As Taras Banakh noted, there is a theorem for Tychonoff powers,

**Theorem** 
Let $\kappa\geq \omega$. If $X^{\omega}$ is Baire, then $X^{\kappa}$ is Baire, where the powers are considered in the Tychonoff product.

When I studied the result, which appears in Kunen and Fleissner's article, only the characterization using games from Baire's spaces is used for the proof.

In fact, if $\kappa>\omega$, they show that, if $X^{\kappa}$ is not Baire then $X^{\omega}$ is not Baire, for this, let $\sigma$ be a winning strategy for Player I in $\textsf{BM}(X^{\kappa})$. We're going to build a winning strategy $\tilde{\sigma}$ for Player I in $\textsf{BM}(X^{\omega})$.

Citing what the article by Fleissner and Kunen mentions: **The ideia is this: Player I relabels the index set as he goes along so that he is in effect playing according to $\sigma$ in $X^{\kappa}$**

Now, if we assume Scheepers' theorem we have the following

**Corollary**
 Let $X$ be a topological space, if for all cardinal $\kappa$, the box power $X^{\kappa}$ is a Baire space then the Tychonoff power $X^{\omega}$ is a Baire space.

I think this can help solve the next question

***Can one prove in ZFC that if a box product of a collection of Baire spaces is Baire, then its Tychonoff product is Baire?***

About products of Baire spaces and spaces with countable cellularity, in **Baire spaces - R. C. Haworth, R. A. McCoy**,  I studied the following result.

**Theorem** *Let $\{X_{\alpha} : \alpha\in A \}$ be a family of Baire spaces such that the product of any countable subcollection is a Baire space and such that $\prod_{\alpha\in A} X_{\alpha}$ has the countable chain condition. Then $\prod_{\alpha\in A} X_{\alpha}$ is a Baire space.*

Comment: The theorem is a well-known game characterization of Baire spaces due to Oxtoby. It can be found in the book of Kechris "Classical Descriptive Set Theory".

Comment: Thank you but the result that I still could not prove is Theorem 46.
It is also known that the reciprocal is not valid because in the article **Barely Baire Spaces** of W. Fleissner and K. Kunen there is a space $X$ such that the Tychonoff power $X^{\omega_{1}}$ is Baire but the box power $X^{\omega_{1}}$ is not Baire.

Comment: Well on page 210 of [Scheepers' article](http://www.math.ac.vn/publications/vjm/VJM_23/No.%202/M.%20Scheepers.PDF), he mentions the relationship between the box topology, Tychonoff product and the Banach-Mazur game and finally comments on Theorem 46.

Answer (score 1):

As Taras Banakh noted, there is a theorem for Tychonoff powers,

**Theorem** 
Let $\kappa\geq \omega$. If $X^{\omega}$ is Baire, then $X^{\kappa}$ is Baire, where the powers are considered in the Tychonoff product.

Now, if we assume Scheepers' theorem we have the following

**Corollary**
 Let $X$ be a topological space, if for all cardinal $\kappa$, the box power $X^{\kappa}$ is a Baire space then the Tychonoff power $X^{\omega}$ is a Baire space.

I think this can help solve the next question

***Can one prove in ZFC that if a box product of a collection of Baire spaces is Baire, then its Tychonoff product is Baire?***

Comment: The implication ($X^\omega$ is Baire $\Rightarrow$ $X^\kappa$ is Baire) holds only for spaces with countable cellularity.

Comment: About products of Baire spaces and spaces with countable cellularity, in **Baire spaces - R. C. Haworth, R. A. McCoy**,  I studied the following result.          
                                                                                            **Theorem** _Let $\{X_{\alpha} : \alpha\in A \}$ be a family of Baire spaces such that the product of any countable subcollection is a Baire space and such that $\prod_{\alpha\in A} X_{\alpha}$ has the countable chain condition. Then $\prod_{\alpha\in A} X_{\alpha}$ is a Baire space._